# node analysis with current source

Tags: current-source, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I have the following problem to solve. I wanna find the current through R1 so i did a node analysis on this circuit. This is what i got so far:

I2 = I1 + I3 (I2 being the current going through R2 etc)

I2 = (VB - 0)/R2 (VB being the node between r1 and r3)

I3 = ((VB - 0)/R3+R4)+I

I1 = (VB-E)/R1

i put all this together and get 28800 = 201VB + 1000*I. Now i dont know what to do with the I aka the current source. Do i convert it to voltage?

Comment: I3 is only equal to = 0.1A;  (VB - 0)/R2 = 0.1A +(E-VB)/R1

Comment: Hmm ok. I just realized isnt it unecesary work to even to node analysis on this circuit to begin with? Cant i just calculate total resistance and do ohm's law to find the total current. Then i take the total current and subtract it with 0.1A?

Comment: No, No, you can't do this. Simply solve this for VB; (VB - 0)/R2 = 0.1A +(E-VB)/R1

Comment: Or you can always use the superposition.

Comment: Sweet, thanks alot. How come you take E-VB? I thought when the current entered the negative side of the Voltage source you took VB-E? Also, you solve VB but what do i do with the 0.1A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you first wrote **I2 = I1 + I3** haven't you ??. All this means that you have assumed that I1 and I2 current flow into VB node. 
I3 is flowing into VB node. And this current is equal to 0.1 A (current source current) because in series circuit we have the same current everywhere and this is why R3 and R4 do not have any influence over I3 current, only current source count here. I1 also flows into VB node and this means that the I1 current is flowing from positive side of the Voltage source through R1 into VB node.
And this is why we have I1 = (E - VB)/R1.

$$I2= I1 + I3$$
$$\frac{VB}{R2}= \frac{E- VB}{R1} + I $$
$$\frac{VB}{600\Omega}= \frac{48V- VB}{400\Omega} + 0.1A $$

Of course, you could write it this way also (all current flow out of the VB node, and that means that I assumed that VB node has the highest voltage/electric potential)

$$I1+I2+I3=0$$

$$\frac{VB - E}{R1}+\frac{VB}{R2}+(-I)=0$$

$$\frac{VB - 48V}{400\Omega}+\frac{VB}{600\Omega}-0.1A=0$$

and the solution is $$VB = 52.8V$$

Comment: Ah ok. Im sorry i confused myself. Thanks for the answer!